# Обязательно ли проходить все курсы для разработки под 1С-Битрикс?

Tags: php, битрикс, веб-программирование

Устроился джуниором в контору, где требуют Битрикс.
Прошел два курса за 4 дня (контент-менеджер и администратор базовый). У меня есть еще максимум неделя чтобы вникнуть.

На данный момент стоит задача незначительной доработки сайтов (создание английской версии сайта и тд).

Могу ли я сразу пройти курс разработчика, минуя дополнительные курсы Админа (модули и бизнес), или придется проходить все подряд? Потребуется больше недели.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я пробовал. ИХМО битрикс - это дыра. Курсы нужно пройти все, поскольку часто возникают смежные задачи. Особенно с настройкой производительности у них серьезная беда. В основном проблемы возникают при настройке серверной части.Так что http://ruhighload.com/post/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5%20highload%20%D0%B8%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%81%20%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%20%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

и битрикс в зубы.Честно они много еще требуют(JS,Jquery,SQL,Node,Angular).Но учи альтернативы тоже.

Удачной стажировки.

Comment: Спасибо. Пока разраба пройду курс, а дальше по ходу остальные буду изучать:) Но погуглив я понял, что оставаться на этой технологии долго не стоит, уж лучше в фреймфорки податься (ларавел, йи и тд). Иначе потеряю потенциал разработчика.